# How can I set the rest of width to an element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is my code:

```css
.rightbar, .container, .leftbar{
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid;
  text-align: center;
}

.rightbar, .leftbar{
  width: 20%;
}

@media (max-width: 599px) { 
    .hidden-mob{
        display: none !important; 
    }
  
}
```

```html
<div class="leftbar">leftbar</div>
<div class="container">container</div>
<div class="rightbar hidden-mob">rightbar</div>
```

I want to set *the rest of `width`* to the `.container` element. I can set `width: 60%;` to it. But I don't want that. Because in a small screen size, `.rightbar` element will be hidden and the width of `.container` should be `80%` automatically.

Anyway, is there any idea how can I handle that?

Comment: why not set the width to 60% and inside your media query set the .container width to 80%? that will override the 60%

Answer (score 2):

Add `.container` to your media query (additionally, you'll need to use slightly smaller percentages due to the border on your elements):

```css
.rightbar,
.container,
.leftbar {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid;
  text-align: center;
}

.container {
  width: 59%;
}

.rightbar,
.leftbar {
  width: 19%;
}

@media (max-width: 599px) {
  .hidden-mob {
    display: none !important;
  }
  .container {
    width: 78%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="leftbar">leftbar</div>
<div class="container">container</div>
<div class="rightbar hidden-mob">rightbar</div>
```

Comment: Border elements can be taken into account by using `box-sizing: border-box` or `width: calc(80% - 2px)`

Answer (score 0):

YOu can use set container to 100% and rest the equivalent of right and left div like the example

```css
.rightbar, .container, .leftbar{
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid;
  text-align: center;
}

.rightbar, .leftbar{
  width: 100px;
}
.container{
  
      width: calc(100% + -206px);
}

@media (max-width: 599px) { 
.hidden-mob{
   display: none !important; 
 }
  
}
```

```html
<div class="leftbar">leftbar
</div><div class="container">container
</div><div class="rightbar">rightbar</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1** Add a media query for the container:

```css
.rightbar,
.container,
.leftbar {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid;
  text-align: center;
}

.rightbar,
.leftbar {
  width: 20%;
}

.container {
  width: 55%;
}

@media (max-width: 599px) {
  .hidden-mob {
    display: none !important;
  }
  .container {
    width: 75%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="leftbar">leftbar</div>
<div class="container">container</div>
<div class="rightbar hidden-mob">rightbar</div>
```

**Option 2** Wrap the elements in a container, and play around with [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/):

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

.rightbar,
.container,
.leftbar {
  border: 1px solid;
  text-align: center;
}

.rightbar,
.leftbar {
  width: 20%;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
}

@media (max-width: 599px) {
  .hidden-mob {
    display: none !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="leftbar">leftbar</div>
  <div class="container">container</div>
  <div class="rightbar hidden-mob">rightbar</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
body{
display: flex;
    display: -webkit-flex;
 
}
.rightbar, .container, .leftbar{
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid;
  text-align: center;
}

.rightbar, .leftbar{
  width: 20%;
}
.container{
width:100%;
}

@media (max-width: 599px) { 
    .hidden-mob{
        display: none !important; 
    }
  
}
```

```html
 <div class="leftbar">leftbar</div>
<div class="container">container</div>
<div class="rightbar hidden-mob">rightbar</div>
```

It will work for responsive as well